# How to avoid GUI freeze when calling Beginthread API?

Tags: delphi

Below just a simple race between 2 button in 2 threads,

and this will freeze other components on the form.

```
procedure moveButton1();
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to 6000 do
    Form1.Button1.Left := Form1.Button1.Left - 1;
  Form1.Caption := 'Button1 won!';
  EndThread(0);
end;
```

procedure moveButton2();
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to 6000 do
    Form1.Button2.Left := Form1.Button2.Left - 1;
  Form1.Caption := 'Button2 won!';
  EndThread(0);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  thread1, thread2,tick : Integer;
  id1, id2 : LongWord;
begin
  thread1 := BeginThread(nil,
                         0,
                         Addr(moveButton1),
                         nil,
                         0,
                         id1);

thread2 := BeginThread(nil,
                         0,
                         Addr(moveButton2),
                         nil,
                         0,
                         id2);
  CloseHandle(thread1);
  CloseHandle(thread2);
end;

Comment: That's a neat idea. Note that after the race is complete, the caption will indicate that the last button to finish won. I recommend using the TThread object to encapsulate your thread.

Comment: My mistake, I should have flipped the captions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The VCL (and parts of the RTL) is not thread-safe, so you cannot move components around from a thread. You have several options:

- Use a `TTimer` component. You don't need a thread and the timer's event handler will be executed in the context of the main thread. The timer was designed exactly for things like that.
- Synchronize all VCL related stuff in the thread. `TThread` provides a static method `Synchronize` that does exactly that.
- Send messages from the thread to the form using `SendMessage` or `PostMessage` and handle this message in the form.

You might also consider to use the `TThread` wrapper class instead of using `BeginThread` and `EndThread`explicitly when working with threads.

Comment: The VCL is designed to be manipulated from one thread only, true, but most of the RTL is thread-safe - depending on what definition one uses. For example, it certainly isn't the case that you must serialize all RTL function calls; the memory manager is thread-safe; almost all routines are thread-safe, because very few manipulate shared state; but I/O using Writeln etc. isn't when targeting the same file (or console).

Comment: You're right of course. It would indeed be a pain if the whole RTL would be unsafe to use from multiple threads. I edited that part.

Answer (score 0):

Using Synchronize() would be the down and dirty method of synchronizing the procedures that move the buttons. Synchronize() forces the method to be run in the main VCL thread. They'll block each other, so only one button can move at a time. This will avoid encountering non-thread safe code in the VCL.

I couldn't recreate the issue of the form freezing though, so I'm not sure that is your issue. You may wish to look elsewhere.

Comment: I do not agree. The VCL thread simply does nothing since everything happens within the two threads. If using `Synchronize` this might indeed be a problem. `Application.ProcessMessages` should not be necessary here.

Comment: The last sentence should be removed, it makes no sense at all. Calling `CloseHandle()` immediately has no negative effect whatsoever, while not calling it would leak system handles. There's no effect on thread *execution*. Also, `Synchronize()` is much more about scheduling code to run in the context of the VCL thread than about synchronizing the code execution. There's other ways to do the latter (like critical sections), but using them instead wouldn't fix the problem.